# How to handle express.js routes?

Tags: node.js, routes, express

i have a routes like

```
app.get('/home',requireLogin,routes.home)

exports.home = function(req, res){
 res.render('index', { title: 'home' });
};
```

now if i want my url look like this

```
/home/menu/someting
```

do i have to create anothoer routes like

```
app.get('/home/menu/someting',requireLogin,routes.newRoutes)
```

or can i just modify the routes.home to handle the rest url,like if there is a second /something do something.

and i know that i can have home/:parameter ,but i need the url look exactly like home/menu/something and after something i will have the :parameter.

just answer me this is it possible to handle the /home and /home/menu in the same routes,no parameters

Comment: Have you considered reading the Express documentation?

Comment: sure i did, i try to use if(req.params[0]) then do something, but it seems that when the url is home/something/ the route wont even go to the routes.home

Comment: Because `/home/something` does not match `/home`. It does match `/home/*` or `/home/:param`, though. Read the *whole* document next time, it's short enough to finish in less than 3 minutes.

Comment: i know that but i really want the url exactly look like home/menu/something, and after something i will have the :parameter

Comment: So the route is `/home/menu/something/:parameter`...

Comment: just answer me this is it possible to handle the /home and /home/menu in the same routes,no parameters

Comment: Yes, `/home/*` will match all those URLs. Then you will have to parse the URL yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both wildcards (`*`) and named parameters (`:parameter`) in your routes.

```
app.get('/home/menu/:something', ...)
```

Then use `req.params.something` for the value.

http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: i know that but i really want the url exactly look like home/menu/something, and after something i will have the :parameter

Comment: Please define what you consider a "parameter". Are you talking about part of a query string (e.g. "home/menu/something?param=value")? If so, you can certainly test its value within a route (in fact that's all you can do with it as far as routing is concerned, since Express's router only looks at the path portion of the URL). P.S. using language like "just answer me" is almost guaranteed to get you downvoted and to make people unwilling to answer your questions.